# Is there a name for unremovable dead code?

Tags: design-patterns

Is there a term for describing a piece of seemingly vestigial/dead code that causes compilation errors when removed? e.g. TF2's Load Bearing Coconut myth

I've asked my coworkers and the consensus is we know there's a word for this, but none of us can remember it.

Comment: Oxbow code? Maybe?

Comment: I don't think so, because oxbow code can typically be deleted without causing problems